# Gsa captcha breaker via php

Tags: php, curl, captcha

The problem is that, when I want to get captcha solution from url server (http://127.0.0.1/gsa_test.gsa)  by hand choosing and submiting file (captcha.jpg), the program returns solution, but when i want to do it with code in php, program returns "[unable to break captcha, sorry]"
Path to folder is good for sure.

link to captcha: http://www.megafileupload.com/rB5R/captcha.jpg

Code:

```
$fields = array(
        'file' => 'path/captcha.jpg',
        'source_url' => '',
        'captcha_platform' => '',
        'action' => 'Submit'
    );

    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, '127.0.0.1/gsa_test.gsa');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    $in = $result;
    preg_match_all('#<html><head><title>GSA CB Result</title></head><body><h1>The solution is :: (.*)</h1></body></html>#Us', $in, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $out = implode($out[1]);
    debug($out);
```

Comment: Maybe needs to be `'file' => '@path/captcha.jpg',` if you need to upload the file to gsa.

Comment: Yes that is correct, thank you :D

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm having the same issue